# How to clear the entire second level cache in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, memcached, second-level-cache, syscache2

I wish to clear the entire second level cache in NHibernate via code.  Is there a way to do this which is independent of the cache provider being used? (we have customers using both memcache and syscache within the same application).

We wish to clear the entire cache because of changes external to the database may have occurred (and we have no guarantees re: which tables/entities were affected, so we have to assume the worst).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should do:

```
sessionFactory.EvictQueries();
foreach (var collectionMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
         sessionFactory.EvictCollection(collectionMetadata.Key);
foreach (var classMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
         sessionFactory.EvictEntity(classMetadata.Key);
```

Comment: Does this still work in recent (eg. 3.3.x) releases of NHibernate?

Comment: @DanP it should. There weren't any major changes to metadata or caching.

Comment: are there any negative repercussions to clearing this in a multi-user environment?  E.g., will this cause web requests to throw a 500 if prior query results are dumped halfway through the logic?

Comment: @ps2goat it shouldn't. It's just a cache.

Comment: The important question I think ps2goat is getting at is whether the cache is thread safe. Will clearing the cache in the middle of another call reading from the cache cause any problems?

Comment: It wouldn't be, but that doesn't mean everyone wrote their third party caches correctly. Just pointing out what it seemed like ps2goat actually meant with their question.